# How to make a half circle progress bar with Kotlin in android-studio?

Tags: android, kotlin, progress-bar, android-progressbar

I am new in Kotlin and trying to make a progress bar that is a HALF CIRCLE in my app and shows how much someone has spend so far.

There are many solutions for round ones and normal ones, but I can't find one for a half circle.

IN MY activity_main.xml FILE:

```
...

<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/circularProgressbar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular"
        android:secondaryProgress="100"/>

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="25$"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

AND IN MY circular.xml FILE:

```
...

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
  <shape
      android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
      android:useLevel="true">

  <gradient
      android:centerColor="#DADADA"
      android:endColor="#999999"
      android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
      android:type="sweep" />
  </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
 <rotate
      android:fromDegrees="270"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toDegrees="270">
  <shape
      android:innerRadiusRatio="6"
      android:shape="ring"
      android:thicknessRatio="20.0"
      android:useLevel="true">

 <rotate
      android:fromDegrees="0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toDegrees="360">
  <gradient
      android:centerColor="#03A9F4"
      android:endColor="#0063B1"
      android:startColor="#68CCFF"
      android:type="sweep" />
  </shape>
 </rotate>
</item>
```

WHAT I WANT is a horizontally cut circle as a progress bar.
I don't know if I am even on the right track and also I don't know how to set the degrees and things in the circular.xml file to get what I want, I tried but every time I changed something the output made no sense.